# How to define a delegate property which need to be initialized delayed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I need to define a property `isBackgroundWindow` by delegate class `PreferenceTool`, but the following code will cause NullPointerException error.

I know that `private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {  }` in `PreferenceTool<T>` is lazy, so the object *this* is not initialized when system invoke `PreferenceTool(this, getString(R.string.IsBackgroundName) , false),` it will cause null error.

I hope to use the code   `private lateinit var isBackgroundWindow: Boolean by PreferenceTool(this, getString(R.string.IsBackgroundName) , false)`, but 
*'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on delegated properties* .

How can I do?

**Main**

```
class UIHome : AppCompatActivity() {   

   //I think the object this is not initialized, it will cause null error.
    private var isBackgroundWindow: Boolean by PreferenceTool(this, getString(R.string.IsBackgroundName) , false) 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home)

        isBackgroundWindow=false
     }

}
```

**Delegate Class**

```
class PreferenceTool<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,  private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {     
        context.defaultSharedPreferences     
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is   context.defaultSharedPreferences    ?? am getting exception here

Comment: You should `import org.jetbrains.anko.*` for  context.defaultSharedPreferences

Comment: ok.i will try with that ...

Comment: check the edited answer .now app is not crashed

Comment: do you get your `NullPointerException` on this line: `context.defaultSharedPreferences` within the `lazy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lateinit the variable isBackground like this way .Your UIHome  class should be

```
 class UIHome : AppCompatActivity() {

 var isBackground: Boolean by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_uihome)
 isBackground = isBackgroundWindow()

}

fun isBackgroundWindow(): Boolean {
val isBackgroundWindow: Boolean by PreferenceTool(
    this, getString(R.string.IsBackgroundName), false
)
return isBackgroundWindow
}
}
```

This is avoid null pointer exception

```
isBackground?.let { 

  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your code can work,  and your code is assign value to `var isBackground` two times. Is there a better way?

Comment: is one time only..did you debug it?

Comment: Thanks! First: `var isBackground: Boolean by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()`, and Second: `isBackground = isBackgroundWindow()`, it seems that your code is a little complex.

Comment: Kotlin is just a suger coating over Java. You will not get context to pass until onCreate method callback. So if you want to have a data member and want to assign a value after constructor, it has be be assigned again.

See this link where Dagger inject context in onCreate method, https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-the-simplest-approach-3e23502c4cab.